# Different query/parameter separators in URIs

Tags: uri, sip, rfc

I wonder what the different parameter separators in (SIP) URIs indicate?

Some separated by `;`, like: `<sip:user@domain.com;foo=bar;x=y>`.

Other are separated by `?` and `&`, like: `<sip:user@domain.com?foo=bar&x=y>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIP separator rules comes from [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) that has been deprecated by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). But with some usage specifications defined in section [19.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-19.1.1).

To summarize a bit, semicolon ";" is used to separate URI parameters, question mark "?" to signal [query component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)'s (stated as "Header fields" in section [19.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-19.1.1)) starting point, and ampersand "&" is used to separate parameter pairs inside query string ("header fields").

Also worth checking Wikipedia entry: [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)

Hope this helps

Comment: Well, I think this is as close as I get to understanding it. It's confusing as I see SIP RFCs use the same parameters with our without a query component - and leading me to think that they should be interpreted in the same way.

Comment: @JohnFear I'm sorry but I don't get what you mean. As far s I recall, RFC3261, only uses "&" in the query component (described as header fields) and ";" to separate URI parameters. I've checked RFC3261 and edited the answer. You can see that, initially, they've different meanings.

Comment: I've been looking at the rfc4244 lately and looking the protocol examples in chapter 4.5 I find query components with ";" separators. Ex '?Reason=SIP;cause=603;'. Is cause a separate URI parameter or part of the Reason query parameter?

Comment: I think I understand what they are doing in the RFC now. Looking at the protocol example in chapter 4.2, the value of the reason parameter is URI encoded (Reason=SIP%3Bcause%3D302) - and this is simply just not illustrated in chapter 4.5. 

@jcm: Thanks for help..

Comment: Well, actually, this means: include header `Reason` with code SIP and cause param 603. For example, if you wanted to include two header fields (Reason and Call-Info), it would look like: `?Reason=SIP;cuase=603&Call-Info=<http://www.foo.com>`