# something about separators in SIP URIs

Tags: uri, sip, rfc

there are two format about history-info part.

1. `History-Info:<sip:xxxx@xx.com;user=phone?Reason=SIP%3Bcause%3D486>;index=1`
2. `History-Info:<sip:xxxx@xx.com;user=phone;Reason=SIP%3Bcause%3D486>;index=1`

just confuse which symbol need use,? or ; and which scenario use ?, which scenario use ;
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different query/parameter separators in URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512652/different-query-parameter-separators-in-uris)

Answer (score 0):

SIP defines URI decoration in its own way.
After a semicolon, it is called *uri parameters*.
After the question mark, it is called *header fields*.

in your case, the first one is correct because *Reason* is a standardized header in SIP https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3326 -  **The Reason Header Field for the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP)**

```
History-Info:<sip:xxxx@xx.com;user=phone?Reason=SIP%3Bcause%3D486>;index=1
```

The received reason header is copied into the header fields of the history-info  URI.

The same apply to other well-known header fields like privacy.

so far, so good but what about the second one ?

```
History-Info:<sip:xxxx@xx.com;user=phone;Reason=SIP%3Bcause%3D486>;index=1
```

Well, it is valid too in the context of history-info because it is easier to accept both for compatibility purpose i guess, please see **Mapping and Interworking of Diversion Information between Diversion and History-Info Header Fields in the Session Initiation Protocol** (SIP)https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7544

In summary, if the piece of information is coming from a *SIP header*, it is maybe better to put it in the *header fields* part of the URI.

Comment: SIP defines URI decoration in its own way. After a semicolon, it is called uri parameters. After the question mark, it is called header fields。------- hello, do you have any rfc about this discription?

Comment: rfc3261#section-19.1.1 SIP and SIPS URI Components
 Its general form, in the case of a SIP URI, is:

      sip:user:password@host:port;uri-parameters?headers

URI parameters: Parameters affecting a request constructed from
         the URI. URI parameters are added after the hostport component and are
         separated by semi-colons.

      Headers: Header fields to be included in a request constructed
         from the URI.Headers fields in the SIP request can be specified with the "?"
         mechanism within a URI.

Comment: ok,thanks, bro, you are very pro